# PHP with Jquery: Inernal Server error (500)

Tags: php, jquery

I have an application that posts data to a php script through jquery's ajax post function. This script validates the data and returns predefined error messages if the data is incorrect which the application parses into a readable form for the client.

The issue is that ajax posts the data just fine to the script, because invalid data is successfully converted into error messages and sent back to the application for parsing. However, when I enter the correct data the script sends back a 500 response error.

The most puzzling part is that on PHP 5.3.8 (my test server) the application works just fine. However, on my clients server (PHP 5.0) the aforementioned error manifests. I am completely lost here. I have tried trapping the post errors with .error but I am not really sure how exactly I am supposed to extract anything meaningful out of this response code.

Comment: Your code... It's not here...

Comment: Use your browsers console to check the Ajax call, and check the responsetext. If possible also enable PHP error reporting on the webserver to see if the internal error is in PHP, and chances are it probably is? It's impossible for us to know why you have an internal server error without seeing much of anything?

Comment: I know, I am sorry but the code really won't make much sense if I post it here. It isn't json by the way. 

I checked the browsers response text with firebug and it is empty. To be precise it says ''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery code have no problem. 
You should log the PHP error, and see what's wrong. Alternatively, if you display errors (what you shouldn't do on a production server), you can have a look directly on Firebug by displaying the request's response.

Comment: If you don't have anything in Firebug, then it's time to check your error log, and if nothing yet, your error reporting settings

Comment: By the way, it doesn't make sense that incorrect code would work just fine on php 5.3 where as it would die on 5.0 Unless I am using some function calls that are exclusively a part of 5.3 and above I don't see how this is possible.

Comment: Many server settings can be different. You have an error, try to find its log. After that it won't be a big deal to debug it.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

Will that work? This is rather annoying because my client hasn't provided me ftp rights to upload and test the application on his server. I have to wait for him to upload and update the files I send in. God...

Comment: ini_set("display_errors", "on") won't work, it has to be done directly in php.ini :( And good luck to debug it if you can't see the logs nor changing this setting!!

Comment: I have got it. I was using a DateTime::createFromFormat() method which is apparently undefined in 5.0 That doesn't sound right... but its a different issue. One that I can solve now that I know what I am dealing with. Thanks!